# How to get salesforce Ids for fields from apex using Schema methods?

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, schema

I tried this approach, but the Salesforce Id is not being returned by `getDescribe` method.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name;
system.debug(' Account field, \'Name\' describe result' + field.getSObjectField().getDescribe());
```

Is there a way to get Salesforce Id for a field, in Apex dynamically?

Comment: Do you need Id of "fields" in custom object and standard object?

Comment: I need field Ids for custom fields on custom objects. But it's good to have a method like, field.getId() to get the salesforce Id of the field for both standard and custom fields on both standard and custom objects.

Comment: I have answered it.

Comment: This is really required feature and salesforce will have to add same in near future. Upvoted Idea @ https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to get Id for a custom or standard field except it you can retrieve name, label type, attributes etc..

The only help can be made is custom field id start from prefix `00N` and in production `CF` appended to `00N`

In addition there is a [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE) for which you can vote.

Conclusion: `getDescribe()` don't support id for field.

Comment: I've voted for on the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I know its old question but I have managed using below code, May be useful for someone. Just use correct object & field name (developerName)

```
string strfieldId = ''; 
                List<EntityDefinition> getFieldIDs= [SELECT DeveloperName,QualifiedApiName,NewUrl,(SELECT Id, DeveloperName, DurableId FROM Fields) FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'Contacts'];
                  for(EntityDefinition entityDefinition : getFieldIDs){
                      for(FieldDefinition  field : entityDefinition.Fields){
                          if(field.DeveloperName == 'Customer'){
                                 List<String> res = field.DurableId.split('\\.');
                                 strfieldId = res[1];
                                 return;
                          }    
                      }
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get salesforce fields Ids using below code sample.

```
String prefix = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + prefix + '/e?nooverride=1');
string html;
Blob pageContent = pr.getContent();
if(pageContent != null) {
         html = pageContent.toString();
  }
 Matcher macher = Pattern.compile('<label for="(.*?)">(<span class="requiredMark">\\*</span>)?(.*?)</label>').matcher(html);
 while(macher.find()) {
                        String label = macher.group(3);
                        String fldId = macher.group(1);
 system.debug(label+'############'+fldId);

 }
```

I think this might be usefull for you if i am wrong then correct me.. Happy coding... :)